# Locale URL /en not working - No such file or directory (/public)

Tags: craft3, localization, multi-site, craft-pro

*Some values have been anonimized and are marked with %value%*

I followed the [steps](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/installation.html) for setting up a local Craft CMS using composer and have the default site running on `%domain%.test`. Now I've made a second site in de admin with the base_url `@web/en` but whenever I go to `%domain%.test/en` it shows the following error:

```
Warning: chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2) in /Users/%user%/.composer/vendor/weprovide/valet-plus/server.php on line 127

Warning: require(/Users/%user%/www/%domain%/public/en/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/%user%/.composer/vendor/weprovide/valet-plus/server.php on line 131

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Users/%user%/www/%domain%/public/en/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/valet-php@7.4/7.4.16/share/valet-php@7.4/pear') in /Users/macbook21/.composer/vendor/weprovide/valet-plus/server.php on line 131
```

The strange part for me is it's looking `/public` instead of the usual `/web` folder?

Anyone know how to fix this issue? I've checked the documentation but can't find any clues as of why it is not working.

---

### Edit 1

Config/general.php

```
<?php
/**
 * General Configuration
 *
 * All of your system's general configuration settings go in here. You can see a
 * list of the available settings in vendor/craftcms/cms/src/config/GeneralConfig.php.
 *
 * @see \craft\config\GeneralConfig
 */

use craft\helpers\App;

$isDev = App::env('ENVIRONMENT') === 'dev';
$isProd = App::env('ENVIRONMENT') === 'production';

return [
    // Default Week Start Day (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday...)
    'defaultWeekStartDay' => 1,

    // Whether generated URLs should omit "index.php"
    'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,

    // The URI segment that tells Craft to load the control panel
    'cpTrigger' => App::env('CP_TRIGGER') ?: 'admin',

    // The secure key Craft will use for hashing and encrypting data
    'securityKey' => App::env('SECURITY_KEY'),

    // Whether Dev Mode should be enabled (see https://craftcms.com/guides/what-dev-mode-does)
    'devMode' => $isDev,

    // Whether administrative changes should be allowed
    'allowAdminChanges' => $isDev,

    // Whether crawlers should be allowed to index pages and following links
    'disallowRobots' => !$isProd,

    // ReCaptcha SiteKey
    'recaptchaSiteKey' => App::env('RECAPTCHA_SITEKEY'),
];
```

Comment: How is your `@web` alias defined? Can you share your `config/general.php` file? It's probably just a configuration issue.

Comment: @moritzLost please see edit, nothing special haven't set up any custom Aliases for `@web` so it should be default. Also any other URL for a entry simply works.

Comment: Hmm, curious ... I'm just noticing that you're using what appears to be an abandoned fork of Laravel Valet. Maybe there's a bug there? You could try updating to the regular Valet by Laravel and see if the error goes away.

Comment: @moritzLost well the weird part is, we have another Craft 3 project (made by a third party) that does work locally. But I can't find out what the difference is between the projects. I've checked the config files, web/index.php and craft file.